# Google Places photos getUrl() is breaking my javascript

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, geturl

I have the following javascript:

```js
function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      place = new Object ({
        name: results[i].name,
        photo: results[i].photos[0].getUrl({'maxWidth': 100, 'maxHeight': 100}),
        loc: results[i].geometry.location,
        rating: results[i].rating,
      })
      places.push(place);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[i].geometry.location,
        id: i,
        visible: false,
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
  }
  newresult();
}
```

If i comment out the following line the function newresult() will run:

```
photo: results[i].photos[0].getUrl({'maxWidth': 100, 'maxHeight': 100}),
```

However, as in the above code, if i do not comment it out the function newresult() will not run. I know that the getUrl function of photo works as it returns a valid url.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what is `results`?  It isn't clear from your code how you're calling this callback function... this is in response to what exactly?

Comment: also are you sure your photos array has length?  What happens if you set a variable to the results of `results[i].photos[0].getUrl({'maxWidth': 100, 'maxHeight': 100})`, which you then add to your 'place' object?

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: how do you use this function(for which method it will be used as callback?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I know that the getUrl function of photo works as it returns a valid
>   url.

Yes, **IF** there is a photo associated with the place! No photo for a place = no `photo` array in the `results[i]` object. And then your code breaks. You must in each iteration check if the `photo` array is present before using it :

```js
place = new Object ({
   name: results[i].name,
   photo: typeof results[i].photos !== 'undefined' 
       ? results[i].photos[0].getUrl({'maxWidth': 100, 'maxHeight': 100})
       : '' //alternative a "nophoto.jpg"
   loc: results[i].geometry.location,
   rating: results[i].rating,
});
```

Here a fiddle based on your code from above -> **http://jsfiddle.net/dX9Gu/**